# Clang static analyzer report ignored by SonarQube community cxx plugin

Tags: sonarqube, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to upload Clang static analyzer reports to SonarQube (I set `sonar.cxx.clangsa.reportPath=analyzer_reports/*/*.plist` to the scan-build output directory containing .plist files), but they got cheerfully ignored, with messages like:

```
'C++ (Community) ClangSASensor' skipped because there is no related rule activated in the quality profile

'C++ (Community) ClangSASensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project

'C++ (Community) ClangSASensor' skipped because there is no related rule activated in the quality profile
```

I ran `sonar-cxx/cxx-sensors/src/tools/clangsa_createrules.py` and copied the output into the quality profile, to no avail.

Any suggestions? Has anybody succeeded in doing this?